# How to generate sphere coordinates in python?

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry

In python how can you say generate coordinates that would appear on a sphere surface. I know the equation is `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2`. But how can you write a function so that, given an integer say `a` which is greater than 1 and `r`, it will give a list `lst` of `(x,y,z)` coordinates such that

- `len(lst) = a`
- the distance between all adjacent points must be the same
  (basically the points should be equidistant)
- each point satisfies `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2`
- the sphere is centered on `(0,0)`.

Thanks

Comment: If these are the only requirements, then ``lst = [(r * cos(i * step), r * sin(i * step), 0) for i in range(a)]`` for any nonzero ``step``. But I have a feeling you need something less trivial than that.

Comment: "the points should be equidistant": strictly speaking, this is not possible, except for 4, 6, 8, 12 or 20 points.

Comment: @omega This is possible for many choices of a but not for all.  What do you want to accomplish?  If you need this for designing a sphere in OpenGL you don't really need equal distance.  If you need this for numerical integration in spherical coordinates you have additional requirements, like the points forming a symmetry of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/algorithms-faq/, have a look at topic 6.06.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 12
r = 0.2
theta = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, a+1))
phi = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, a+1))

x = r * np.einsum("i,j->ij", np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))
y = r * np.einsum("i,j->ij", np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
z = r * np.einsum("i,j->ij", np.ones(len(theta)), np.cos(theta))
xyz = np.array([x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten()])
```

The only issue here is that the number of points is a^2. But I suppose you can tune it to as you need it.